# Is there a way to combine Conv2D layers with LSTM?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

I'm setting up a keras model with Conv2D and LSTM layers and i try the following code .. i am trying not to reshape the LSTM layer but it also gives me an error that the index is out of range. I have searched a lot but i couldn't figure out where is the problem or how to fix it
The images which are the input to the CNN model are 128*128

**I updated my code**

```
num_steps = 50
lats = 128
lons = 128
features = 4
out_feats = 3

model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'), 
                          input_shape=(1,128, 128, 3)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Reshape((8, 8, 1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(UpSampling2D((2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(out_feats, (3,3), padding='same')))
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

X_data = np.array(X_data)
X_datatest = np.array(X_datatest)

hist=model.fit(X_data, X_data,epochs=15,batch_size=128,verbose = 2,validation_data=(X_datatest, X_datatest))
```

but it gives me the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\bdyssm\Desktop\Master\LSTMCNN2.py", line 107, in 
>       hist=model.fit(X_data, X_data,epochs=15,batch_size=128,verbose = 2,validation_data=(X_datatest, X_datatest))   File
>   "C:\Users\bdyssm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 952, in fit
>       batch_size=batch_size)   File "C:\Users\bdyssm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 751, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='input')   File "C:\Users\bdyssm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py",
>   line 128, in standardize_input_data
>       'with shape ' + str(data_shape)) ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got
>   array with shape (2892, 128, 128, 3)

This is the model summary 
[image]

Comment: it should be Reshape((-1, 28)) (note the extra parenthesis to make a tuple). But I don't see why this reshape is necessary at all.

Comment: i tried not to reshape but its also gives me an error "the list index is out of range"

Comment: Error messages alone aren't that helpful, you should update your question with the complete traceback.

Comment: Ok.. i have updated the error with the traceback